# Como aplicar DAO (Hibernate) y un servicio rest

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, patrones-de-diseño

Estoy intentando hacer un servicio Rest con Java en SpringBoot que se conecte con una base de datos relacional.
Al momento de devolver un objeto tipo DAO(Hibernate) me devuelve toda la informacion, pero quiero ocultar algunos datos por ejemplo el id del objeto y queria saber que soluciones tengo ?
Crear una Clase que voy a devolver el Rest ?
Setear esos atributos como null así no expongo datos sensibles ?
Alguna otra solución será bien recibida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si lo que deseas hacer es que no se envien esos elementos puedes utilizar esta anotacion de jackson asi

```
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String nombreUsuario;
```

Si deseas hacerlo a traves de DAO aqui hay [un tutorial de como hacerlo](https://refactorizando.blog/mybatis-con-spring-boot-como-hacer-persistencia/)(viene en el repositorio git):